# Configure IIS to accept or filter user certificate by specific issuer

Tags: ssl, iis, ssl-certificate

You can easily configure IIS to use specific certifcate for SSL using IIS Manager. However I found difficult to filter which user certificate is shown in selection when user opens browser on web page. The selection contains all valid user cerificates but I want only specific certificate to be listed (prefered by specific CA) and I know that this is possible.

I have already figured out that this is not client side but rather IIS side settings. Does anyone know how this can be configured?

Comment: How did you figure out it is an IIS setting. In IIS you can only accept or require client certificates, but can not specify any filters. And how do you know this is possible at all?

Comment: If I access specific IIS based web site then browser (tested on IE and Chrome) only lists specific user cetificate apart from my site where all user certificates are listed. I assume there must be some IIS settings that can be modified using cmd command. Most likely this is what I am looking for.

Comment: Interesting, I've never seen that, but I would say that has to do with the crypto configuration in Windows rather than IIS, like supporting certain ciphers and hashes. I doubt you can filter based on CA and I'm pretty sure there is nothing about this in IIS itself. Maybe you can check whether the certs that are not listed for some sites have a SHA1 signature algorithm

Comment: I have checked signature algorithm and it turns out that in both cases SHA1 in used and they have the same public key length... so we can rule this out.

Answer (score 1):

A little bit late but to filter certificates you can use IIS Client Certificate Mapping Authentication.
Follow [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/authentication/iisclientcertificatemappingauthentication/) on how to do this. There you can filter in IIS what kind of Client certificates you want to allow.

To limit the selection of the popup a browser shows you need to send the trusted issuer list. Then the browser will only show certificates that your server trusts. From IIS8.5 and higher this is default false. [See this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/dn786429(v=ws.11)#management-of-trusted-issuers-for-client-authentication)

To do this set: **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\SendTrustedIssuerList** to **DWORD** value **1**

Be aware that there is limit of trusted issuers that can be send! If this is to long it can be problematic in the way that there is a possibility the client wont see all the valid certificates in the popup.